# Ansible uses Proxy Server for Local IP Address, how to "Bypass Proxy Server for Local Addresses"

Tags: curl, proxy, ansible, jenkins-plugins

I am running a jenkins server on *10.251.130.45:8080*.
the server is behind a proxy.

- I want to install some jenkins plugins using the ansible module:
  jenkins_plugin
- The plugins are being fetched from the standard location:
  "updates_url": "https://updates.jenkins-ci.org" So that needs to go
  through the proxy.
- The ip-address based calls however need to go to the local jenkins
  instance.

However this fails. I tested both using ip, and localhost as url for the jenkins instance. it appears as all go to the proxy.

**How can I make ansible only run the DNS based queries through the proxy?**

Previously I have been using:

```
environment:
  http_proxy: http://webproxy.ec.local:9090
  https_proxy: http://webproxy.ec.local:9090
```

and just setting the proxies to "" to reset on tasks where the localhost address was used, however, now I need to use both localhost and a remote url.
  And ofcourse I dont want the localhost of the proxy!

```
failed: [localhost] (item=authorize-project) => {
    "details": "HTTP Error 502: cannotconnect",
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null,
            "backup": null,
            "content": null,
            "delimiter": null,
            "directory_mode": null,
            "follow": false,
            "force": false,
            "force_basic_auth": true,
            "group": "jenkins",
            "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
            "jenkins_home": "/var/lib/jenkins",
            "mode": "0644",
            "name": "authorize-project",
            "owner": "jenkins",
            "regexp": null,
            "remote_src": null,
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "src": null,
            "state": "present",
            "timeout": 500.0,
            "unsafe_writes": null,
            "updates_expiration": 86400,
            "updates_url": "https://updates.jenkins-ci.org",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "url_password": "admin",
            "url_username": "admin",
            "use_proxy": true,
            "validate_certs": true,
            "version": null,
            "with_dependencies": true
        }
    },
    "item": "authorize-project",
    "msg": "Cannot get CSRF"
```

*Some tests using curl:*

the localhost call gives a 502 just as ansible did.

```
curl -X HEAD --proxy http://webproxy.ec.local:9090 -i localhost:8080 // 502

curl -X HEAD --proxy http://webproxy.ec.local:9090 -i 10.251.130.45:8080  // FAIL, timeout

curl -X HEAD -i http://10.251.130.45:8080 // 200 ok
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**no_proxy** env variable solves this by adding the necessary exceptions.

```
environment:
    http_proxy: http://webproxy.ec.local:9090
    https_proxy: http://webproxy.ec.local:9090
    no_proxy: 127.0.0.1, localhost, 10.251.*.*
```

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31307